# Add every element in a vector in R without using 'SUM' function

Tags: r

I am trying to get the total of every element in a vector without using any inbuilt functions:

```
x <- 1:6
arraysum <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    y <- 0
    y <- i+1
  }
  print(y)
}
```

But I am getting output 7 instead of 21. Could someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: You start `y` with 0 and then immediately set it to `i + 1` which means that y takes on the following values in the for loop: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.  Try moving the `y <- 0` outside the for loop and changing the assignment to `y <- y + x[i]`. That will take care of the problem and make the function work with `x` containing any values.

Comment: If you reset the value to 0 at every pass through the loop   ... what do you expect? Think about about it a bit more.

Comment: Furthermore, your code is not trying to sum up the elements of x but the indices 1:6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(`+`, x)
# [1] 21
```

Comment: The same can be achieved with `sum(x)` as well but OP mentioned `I am trying to get the total of every element in a vector without using any *inbuilt* functions:`. You might want to include a `for` loop in your answer.

Comment: @RonakShah The problem cannot be solved if you interepret it literally. Even `+` is a built-in function.

Comment: Haa, yes but I am assuming that this is an assignment where the professor have told them not to use any in-built functions in R but I can be wrong.

Comment: @RonakShah Agreed, I assume the professor means "built-in functions specifically designed for the purpose of summing vector elements".

Comment: @SvenHohenstein,@RonakShah I corrected my code using Edward and 42's suggestions and it works fine. This is no assignment, there is no professor and I am no student, I am totally new to programming and was testing myself with this scenario.